# Not executing last line of for loop & not exiting when done - C

Tags: c, opengl, for-loop

I am trying to write a program with OpenGL which takes in a list of heights (height map) and spits out a landscape. I am running into an issue when reading in the map. I have the code below as my loops to read in and store the values in an array (heights). It compiles fine and runs but it gets hung up on the last iteration through the loop, it will print out everything fine until the the point where i=rows and it does not print out "read in row finish" and just gets hung up.

```
printf("reading in the height map\n");
for(i=0; i < rows; i++){
   printf("read in row start\n");
   for(j=0; j < cols; j++){
      scanf("%f", &cur_height);
      heights[point].x = j;
      heights[point].y = i;
      heights[point].z = cur_height;
      point++;
      printf("%d %d\n",j, cols);
   }
   printf("%d\n", point);
   printf("read in row finish");
}
```

EDIT:
Also, as a little bit of extra context heights is an array or points, declared as:

```
#define NUM_POINTS 202750
typedef struct point_type{
   float x, y, z;
} pt_t;
pt_t heights[NUM_POINTS];
```

Comment: Probably you have written beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: You increase `point` once outside the inner loop, making it skip one entry in the `heights` array. Also, are you sure the `heights` array is large enough to fit all entries?

Comment: Also, by doing e.g. `i = 0; i <= rows; i++` you are actually looping `rows + 1` times. You might want to change the condition to `i < rows`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my heights array is big enough, its set up for a 860*916 map and here I am only trying to do a 450*500 or around there map, so I think it should be fine. Also thanks for pointing out the point increment, thats not what I wanted.

Comment: I changed my condition back to i < rows and same for j, however the last print out from the loop is 
"434 436
 435 436
 101588"    but its not getting the "read in row finish"

Comment: Are you typing these in each time you test? What happens if you send an EOF?

Comment: I am reading in from a file, using "application<filename" and sending a premature EOF does nothing

Comment: Of what type are i and j?

Comment: they are both integers

Answer (score 1):

Use right condition in loops

```
for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
```

and

```
for(j=0; j<cols; j++)
```

Comment: i have my loops set back to that and its still getting hung up after the last printf("%d", point); statement and not exiting the loop

Comment: @RossBrown What have you done to verify that you're not writing beyond the bounds of the array?

Comment: I just setup a print statement for point everytime it is incremented, and it only goes up to 202740, and my array is initialised with a size of 202750 just for a little extra, points should only be going to 202740 which it is, so Im fairly certain I am not going beyond the bounds

Comment: @RossBrown Can you tell me value of rows, cols and size of heights also what is printed by last printf("%d", point); statement before hung.

Comment: value of rows is 465 and cols is 436, the last printf of point is 202740, and when I printed the values of i and rows next to each other the last one was 463 for i and 465 for rows